# How to make python ELK APM log correlation works

Tags: python, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I am using python with `ecs_logg` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/python/current/installation.html. It output to a file.

Then I am having a logstash reading the logs. Here is an example of the log

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-31T11:55:49.303Z","log.level":"warning","message":"Cannot get float field. target_field: fxRate","ecs":{"version":"1.6.0"},"log":{"logger":"parser.internal.convertor","origin":{"file":{"line":317,"name":"convertor.py"},"function":"__get_double"},"original":"Cannot get float field. target_field: fxRate"},"process":{"name":"MainProcess","pid":15124,"thread":{"id":140000415979328,"name":"MainThread"}},"service":{"name":"Parser"},"trace":{"id":"264c816a6cdd1f92a26dfad80bdc3e91"},"transaction":{"id":"a8a1ed2ab0b38ca0"}}
```

Here is the config of my logstash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/usr/share/logstash/logs/*.log"]
        type => "log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        # Move keys from 'message' json log to root level
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        id => "Transform"
        # Define the environment such as dev, uat, prod...
        add_field => {
            "environment" => "dev"
        }
        # Rename 'msg' key from json log to 'message'
        rename => {
            "msg" => "message"
        }
        # Add service name from `tag`
        copy => {
            "tag" => "service.name"
        }

    }

}
```

It seems that the logstash didn't index the field and insert into the ELK. As a result the transaction id didn't extracted out and the APM cannot correlated with the logs.

I would like to ask what is the missing part in the logstash config? and how to activate the log correlation.

## Thanks

Hi @Colton,

Thanks for your reply, I have a screen shot here and try to clarify the issue.

I see that the document is there. `transaction` and `trace` id are there also.

[image]

I can also see that types are also exist:

[image]

I want to show logs on the APM page:

[image]

After searching the apm index, I see for example :

[image]

This id exist on both log
And I search this transaction id from APM, I can see it there

[image]

Index management

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what happens with the document in Elasticsearch? Maybe show a sample document? Is logstash not creating a document at all, or is the document wrong in some way?

Comment: I included more pictures in the question. Thanks

Comment: So the document is there, has all the log correlation fields... what's the behavior you're expecting? From your screenshots it looks like everything is working as designed.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, I would like to show the logs on the APM page not just only pushing logs and view it on discovery. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for being patient with all my clarifications! The next thing to check is whether you have logs that *match* with a transaction ID that's also in Elasticsearch. So, pick a log, grab the `transaction.id`, and search for a transaction document in the APM index with that `transaction.id`. I just want to make sure all the data is in an matches before we try to debug why it's not showing up in the APM section of kibana.

Comment: Hi @ColtonMyers, thank you so much for you help. It is a good way for trouble shooting, thank you so much for your time. I added the screen capture, hopefully I didn't misunderstood the index you are referring to.

Comment: You did screenshot a transaction ID, but the important thing is to find a *matching* ID in one of your log documents. The APM UI can only bring in logs with a matching transaction ID, so I wanted to make sure there was one to find. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @ColtonMyers, I searched from the APM and I see the transaction over there. Is that a correct place for me to confirm that ? Thanks

Comment: Another thing to check is that you have your logs in the index configured in your logs UI. The APM app doesn't check all indices for logs.

Comment: I am not very sure where is the index configuration you are referring to, I added a new screen capture with the index management page, is that what you are looking for ?

Thanks

Comment: Go to the logs section of the Kibana UI, and then go to Settings at the top. Here's a screenshot: https://capture.dropbox.com/AERT8XOwRjlCY4KH -- you need to make sure your log index is included in "Log Indices"

Comment: I'll add that comment as an answer, then you can mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the APM app to pick up the logs in Kibana, you have to make sure the index which stores your logs is configured in the logs UI in Kibana.

Go to the logs section of the Kibana UI, and then go to Settings at the top. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Logs UI in Kibana]

You need to make sure your log index is included in "Log Indices".

Answer (score 1):

try to replace trace.id with trace_id when you store your log into elasticsearch,ie parse log fields with trace_id.